# How to Add an array of ints to stored procedure in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

Is it possible to send n ints to a stored procedure as parameters? The reason is because I need to select n orders and call a sproc to then send back only those order ids I selected.

I know how to call one, but I would prefer to call a set of orders with row size n if possible.

```
select * 
from order 
where orderid =1 or orderid = 2 or orderid = 100 ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to send n ints but not as parameters unfortunately.

```
SELECT * FROM Order WHERE orderid in (1, 2, 100)
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a nvarchar(4000) with the string "(1, 2, 100, ...)" and then use that in my sproc somehow?

Comment: Yes but it's dangerous, slow and smelly.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your comma separated parameter to XML, use that to fill a table variable of ID's that you then can use in your queries.

```
create procedure GetOrderList @OrderIDs varchar(8000)
as
-- Convert paramter to xml
declare @XMLStr varchar(8000)
set @XMLStr = '<R><I ID="'+replace(@OrderIDs, ',', '"></I><I ID="')+'"></I></R>'

-- Table variable that holds the ID's
declare @IDs table (ID int)

-- Load the XML document and insert id's to @IDs
declare @idoc int
exec sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc out, @XMLStr
insert into @IDs
    select ID from openxml(@idoc, '/R/I',1) with (ID  int)
exec sp_xml_removedocument @idoc

-- Use @IDs in your query
select O.OrderID
from [order] as O
  inner join @IDs as I
    on O.OrderID = I.ID
```

Test

```
exec GetOrderList '1,2,3,4'
```

Result

```
OrderID
-------
1
2
3
4
```